# Find all solutions of the 2'nd order ODE: $x'' + x =0$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find all solutions of the 2'nd order ODE: $x'' + x=0$.

I've found by inspection of $x (t)=e^{at} $ that $\cos t $, $\sin t $ are solutions. How do I see, that all linear combinations of these are all solutions of the ODE ?

A hint is given: compare with the complex ODE: $z' =-iz $.

Comment: Express it in terms of $y(t):=x'(t)$, solve, and then use $x(t)=\int^t y(s)\,{\mathrm d}s$.

Comment: I a did mistake. I've edited.

Comment: I was about to ask how you got your solution before you edited, because the solutions $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ certainly didn't satisfy $x'' + x' = 0$

Comment: Is this equation difficult to solve ?

Comment: To compare with the complex ODE, introduce the phase plane $x, y=\dot x$ and identify it with the complex plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solutions of a homogeneous ODE form a vector space, hence you only need to check that $f(t)=\sin t,g(t)=\cos t$ are independent solutions. This follows from the Pythagorean theorem, since the Wronskian of $f,g$ is given by:
$$ W(f,g) = \left|\begin{array}{cc} f & f'\\ g & g' \end{array}\right|=\left|\begin{array}{cc} \sin t & \cos t\\ \cos t & -\sin t \end{array}\right|=-1\neq 0. $$

Comment: How do I know the dimension of this vector space is $2$ ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen: The dimension of the vector space is given by the order of the ODE: two, in this case.

Comment: I didn't knew this. Is it hard to prove ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen: no, it is not. Here we have two independent solutions, so the dimension is at least $2$. A solution $h$, however, is fixed once we know $h(0)$ and $h'(0)$ by the Cauchy-Lipshitz theorem, so the dimension is at most $2$.

Comment: What do you mean by fixed ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen: that there is only one function satisfying $x+x''=0,x(0)=x_0,x'(0)=x_1.$